# custom scroller(jQuery scroller ) in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, twitter-bootstrap

Can we add custom scroller(jQuery scroller ) in bootstrap dropdown ?

*Like this note red line in the picture*   [image]

Comment: Is this because you have long dropdowns?

Comment: Yes it is very long drop-down , Any solution ?

Comment: Can you spot the class of your drop down menu then style it with a fixed `height` and `overflow-y:scroll`?

Comment: NO , I mean custom jQuery scroll down

Comment: You may try the script which used in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bUxDE/22/

Answer (score 0):

I know that's been a long time, but a had the same issue and i manage to do it so maybe it can help someone.
I used [Malihu Custom Scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) with my Bootstrap Dropdown and it worked perfectly. 
Don't forget to put a height or max-height to the dropdown that will receive the scrollbar.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Cause I have a troubles with bootstrap styles and two dives which auto generated by this plugin